# How to hide tabs on landing page (Home page) in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to the ionic framework.

I am working on an app and I don't want tabs in the landing page.

How to hide tabs on landing page (Home page) in ionic.

In the below example its working when you click on the Scientific Facts, I am not getting how to do it can any one please help me with this issue.

[Example](http://codepen.io/toddhalfpenny/pen/bNyLYB)

```
  angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
})

.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, $el) {
          $rootScope.hideTabs = 'tabs-item-hide';
          $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              $rootScope.hideTabs = '';
          });
      }
  };
});
```

Comment: show your tabs.html and home.html code please

Comment: @User123 use ng-if or ng-show or ng-hide in your html depending on your need

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem... try making the Home page a separate state/template/controller outside of the nested tabs.logic. The easiest way I found to do this was in two steps:

1. Remove your Home from the nested `.state('tabs.home',` logic to just `.state('home',`
2. Remove the `views: {` portion and just add the `templateUrl` and
   `controller` directly.

(I also moved it to the top of the list for clarity)

I've modified the code below as an example:

```
$stateProvider
 .state('home', {
   url: "/home",
       templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
       controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
 })

//everything below here is the same, but I left it for context

 .state('tabs', {
   url: "/tab",
   abstract: true,
   templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
 })
 .state('tabs.facts', {
   url: "/facts",
   views: {
     'home-tab': {
       templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
     }
   }
 })
```